# Adding several y-axis and data to existing barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, yaxis

I have tried to find answers how to add several y-axis to a barplot with different ways to illustrate my data, but have been unable to find what I want to do. 
So far I have managed to make a nice looking barplot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8S3C.png).
[image: barplot]

Now I want to add more y-axis to add other variables as points above my bars like in this barplot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwE0C.png).

[image: barplot with more y axis]

My code looks so far like this:

```
dataH <- read.delim("~/Speciale/Data - Narsarsuaq/barplot_H.txt")

bilanH <- aggregate(cbind(X189,X197,X205,X212)~treatment , data=dataH , mean)
rownames(bilanH) <- bilanH[,1]
bilanH <- as.matrix(bilanH[,-1])

lim <- 30


error.bar <- function(x, y, upper, lower=upper, length=0.1,...){
  arrows(x,y+upper, x, y-lower, angle=90, code=3, length=length, ...)
}


stdevH <- aggregate(cbind(X189,X197,X205,X212)~treatment , data=dataH , sd)
rownames(stdevH) <- stdevH[,1]
stdevH <- as.matrix(stdevH[,-1]) * 1.96 / 10


ze_barplot <- barplot(bilanH , beside = T ,legend.text=T,density=c(0,15,15,15) , angle=c(0,45,0,135) , col="black" ,main="Total emission - High elevation", ylim=c(0,lim) , ylab="Emission rate (ng  cm-2 leaf area  h-1)")
barplotH <- error.bar(ze_barplot,bilanH, stdevH)
```

Is there an easy way to add points to my barplots?